# Breaking up an array of document.getElementsByTagName("img");

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I am using the following to find all of the images on a given page:

```
function img_find() {
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgSrcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    ;
    imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
}
return imgSrcs;
}
```

I think define a new variable `img_find = img_find();` and then I write the variable `document.write(img_find);`

This is my output string `"http://www.domain.com/image.png"`

I want to break this up so eventually I could write

```
document.write("<img src='"+img_find+"'/>");
```

Which would display the images.

However as of now all it outputs is

```
src='http://www.domain.com/image.png,http://www.domain.com/image.png'
```

which obviously won't display an image.

Does anybody know how I can re-write this so I can use `document.write("<img src='"+img_find+"'/>");` and have it display all the images on the current page?

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question quite a bit to clarify it. You have `;` after `{` in your for loop, I hope that's a mistake? I'm suprised this loop runs.

Comment: He (I think) removed a piece of code he did not want to appear in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is time for the magnificent `for loop`! Saving desperate coders everywhere!

```
var img_ = img_find();

for(var i=0; i<img_.length; i++){
    document.write("<img src='"+img_[i]+"'/>");
}
```

Comment: More about the magnificent for loop: @ http://javascriptgarden.info/#array.general

Comment: At fourth line, `img_find[i]` is must be `img_[i]`. I think.

Comment: @Chris, just so you know, I did not use `var img_find` because I thought it would conflict with the function. Unless, of course, that is the OP's intention.